# CSS Ordering Convention for which tags to specify first

Tags: css, conventions

I typically place the rules in my CSS in the same order as they are in the HTML. But what about global rules like how I format my `input`,`textarea`,`p`,`tr`,`th` and stuff like that? Is there a convention on which order the rules should go in?

Obviously there are situations when the rules have to be in a certain order to work.

Comment: You could maybe check the standard firefox css in your "Program Files"-folder. I assume/really hope they do it in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use one line per rule notation now, try to keep it organized and easy to read. It minimizes scrolling and it is easier to sort the rules that way.

Answer (score 3):

I just put "global" properties of CSS in their own stylesheet all together. So for instance: put in `tr, td, input, table,` etc in their own stylesheet and the rest of custom .classes and #divs in their own.

This simplifies it the best and keeps it organized.

Answer (score 2):

Global CSS rules can go on a file (i.e. global-style.css) - these will apply to all pages.
Specific CSS rules can go a separate file (i.e. login-style.css) - on this second file, you can override the default look-feel of the global CSS if desired.

You would only include the second file in the HTML files you need the different look-feel (from the global one)